# Optimum exists but not extreme point in Standard Form LP problem?

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

**Standard form problem**

> $$\min \bar c^T \bar x \text{ so that } A \bar x=\bar b, \bar x\geq \bar 0$$

I am thinking the point [II (Finnish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUnUW.png) i.e. optimum exists but it is not extreme point, why it cannot be a standard form problem? Basically, can standard-form problem have the matrix $A$ a zero matrix and the vector $\bar b$ a zero vector?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Standard_form) states no non-zero constraints for $A$ or $\bar b$. There may be simpler explanation for the statement *"Optimum exists but not extreme point in Standard Form LP problem"*.

Comment: Your example isnt a linear programming problem, since $f(x)=-1/x$ cannot be written in the form of $f(x)=c^Tx$...

Comment: Because $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x_1}$ is not linear... The cost must be of the form $\sum_k c_k x_k$.

Comment: Linear means what I just wrote, the cost must be of the form $\sum_k c_k x_k$.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the design variable. It is what you are trying to solve for.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the point. Now back to Q, can a standard form problem have $A=0$ and $\bar b=\bar 0$?

Comment: Well, it can, but it is pointless, as either the cost is always zero, or it can be made as small as you want.

Comment: Any point will solve $\min_x 0x$.

Comment: @copper.hat correct! And it is in standard form. Is the statement false? Or do we have different definitions for the standard form problem...cannot see yet, thinking. Hey, does the term *"optimum"* here means *"unique optimum"*?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is here. If $\min \{ c^T x | x \geq 0 \}$ has a solution, then it has a solution that is an extreme point ($x=0$).

Comment: @copper.hat the material makes this statement *"If the feasible set is non-empty and unbounded, then: if optimum exists in LP problem and it is not an extreme point, then it cannot be in Standard Form LP problem"* -- I cannot understand this. I am trying to understand the statement in brackets in the slide.

Comment: It is not true as stated. Take $\min \{ x_1 | x \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^3, x_3 = 0 \}$. Then the solution set is $\{(0, x_2, 0)\}_{x_2 \geq 0 }$ which contains points that are not extreme. (A solution that is extreme exists, of course, this is a basic LP result.)

Comment: @copper.hat check my answer, I understood it now what my teacher tried to say -- verified from him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of them is right at once. In standard form problem, you have always at least one extreme point hence the condition II cannot be correct with standard form problems.

So only one of them is correct each time with feasible non-empty unbounded set:

1. Optimum exists and it is extreme point
2. Optimum exists but no extreme point
3. The cost in optimum is $-\infty$

where the condition 2 can never occur with standard-form problem, repeating.